# what is the number of application masters spawned in oozie workflow

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, oozie

I have a Oozie workflow on Yarn comprising a spark action, optional shell action to collect logs in case of error and email notification action. When I try to run the workflow the spark action ends up sitting in ACCEPTED state with the following message:

> Application is added to the scheduler and is not yet activated. User's AM resource limit exceeded.  Details : AM Partition = <DEFAULT_PARTITION>; AM Resource Request = <memory:8192, vCores:1>; Queue Resource Limit for AM = <memory:12288, vCores:1>; User AM Resource Limit of the queue = <memory:8192, vCores:1>; Queue AM Resource Usage = <memory:4096, vCores:1>;

There are two aspects that I don't really understand about what this message is saying:

1. > Queue AM Resource Usage = <memory:4096, vCores:1>

- I am guessing that the Oozie Lancher AM is using the 4096 mb, is this correct?

2. > AM Resource Request = <memory:8192, vCores:1>; Queue Resource Limit for AM = <memory:12288, vCores:1>; User AM Resource Limit of the queue = <memory:8192, vCores:1>;

- am I reading this correctly, in that the queue AM resource limit is 12,288 mb but user AM limit is 8,192 mb?
- if the AM request is 8192 mb, who exactly is requesting this? are there 2 extra AMs being spawned, at 4096 mb each?

Thank you!

Comment: I would check your `yarn-site.xml` file to see how large each AM is going to be. Similarly, you can configure the memory the spark driver and executors should be given

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for your note, the one property that jumps out in yarn-site.xml is 

```xml
<property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>4096</value>
  </property>
```

Comment: @OneCricketeer also, the message seems to point specifically to AM resource requests so do the driver/executor allocation matter?